# Remove blue border around b-nav-item-dropdown

Tags: css, vue.js

I've tried to remove the blue border which comes when focus the `b-nav-item-dropdown` in Vue bootstrap. Tried many example but didn't work. I've done as follows.

**Vue template**

```
<b-nav-item-dropdown class="nav-item dropdown nav-dropdown-custom" text="LANGUAGES">
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">EN</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">ES</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">RU</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">FA</b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-dropdown-custom {
    color: black !important;
    opacity: 100%;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.nav-dropdown-custom:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Still I get the border like,

[image]

Is there a possibility to remove this border from the drop down. Please suggest a fix for this.
Thanks

Comment: How can others help you without you posting a demo of it? Use this: https://codesandbox.io/ and make sure it is the same as the image.

Comment: You're not targeting the correct element. You should target `.nav-link.dropdown-toggle` with `outline: none;`. It's all visible in your dev tools.

Comment: To add on @amaury's answer, you should use the devtools to find out if it's either `focus`, `active` or idk. Helping you here is difficult. Maybe provide a [example]. Btw, this one is for a11y so you may keep it rather than removing it.

Comment: I agree with @kissu, if you're removing the default style for focus / active, don't forget to recreate one that will match your needs. It's here for a good reason.

Answer (score -1):

Try with Adding `border:none`  or `border:0` to class `nav-item`

```
.nav-item{
  border : none !important;
 }
```

`!important` keyword is used to overwrite the defined css

Comment: Still not fixed!

Answer (score -1):

Try with adding `border-0` to `class name`

```
<b-nav-item-dropdown class="nav-item dropdown nav-dropdown-custom border-0" text="LANGUAGES">
```

refernce : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/borders/

Comment: I tried this already. But didn't work. This border comes after I click on the dropdown and close it. It might be when the dropdown is focused.

Comment: are you tried with adding` border none` to 'focus:` selection class

Comment: try with changing `class name ` to different name because some time there will be css for bootsrap classname like `nav-item` and `custom` so try with changing different names